# Conditional_formatting to find duplicate values using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to have a class highlight any duplicate values in column A using openpyxl.

Currently column A has the following values:

```
A
A
B
C
A
C
A
```

The end result would have all of the A's and C's cells colored in red.  My code below doesn't throw any errors, but the file when opened after being ran through this doesn't have the any coloring in the duplicated cells.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import formatting, styles
from openpyxl.formatting import Rule 
   
class Duplicates():
    def __init__(self, wb2):
        self.wb2 = wb2
        ws2=self.wb2.active
        self.red_fill = styles.PatternFill(start_color ='ffc7ce', end_color = 'ffc7ce', fill_type = 'solid')
        dxf= styles.differential.DifferentialStyle(fill=self.red_fill)
        rule = Rule(type='duplicateValues',dxf=dxf,stopIfTrue = None)
        ws2.conditional_formatting.add('$A:$A',rule)
        self.wb2.save('testing.xlsx')

Duplicates(wb2)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, it work for me

```
red_text = Font(color="9C0006")
red_fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFC7CE")
dxf = DifferentialStyle(font=red_text, fill=red_fill)
rule = Rule(type="duplicateValues", text="highlight", dxf=dxf)
wsRes.conditional_formatting.add('B1:B10000', rule)
```